# Navigation bar does not convert in RTL for arabic language in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, localization, uinavigationbar

I have functionality for user to change language within app.

If I change the language within the app without set the root view controller, navigation bar does not convert its layout to RTL.

The current page view controller text will be changed according to language which I set from my App

I put my code here what i have done to change the auto layout for RTL & LTR

```
    if let languageArray = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: APPLE_LANGUAGE_KEY) as? Array<String> {

        switch languageArray[0] {
        case KLanguage_ar:
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
            break
        case kLanguage_en:
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }

            break
        default:
            break

        }   
    }
```

If I change the root view controller after change my App language, it is working fine.

So what should I do same thing without change the root view controller?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I my case UIBarButtonItem image is not changing for back button.

Comment: Still haven't found a solution for this either